# Integration of real analytic two variable function against smooth function with compact support is real analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R} $ is real analytic in the first entry, say $x$, and smooth ($\mathcal{C}^\infty$) in the second entry $y$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R} $ is smooth with compact support. We define
$$ \psi(x)=\int f(x,y)g(y) dy$$
Derivatives with respect to $x$ commute with the integral, so due to the compact support of $g$ the map $\psi$ is smooth.

Question:
Is $\psi$ real analytic?
If not, what additional assumption can be imposed on $ g$ to make $\psi$ real analytic?

Edit:

Question:
Does the situation change, if $f$ is real analytic as a function on $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m  $ entirely?

Comment: What do you get with $n=m=1, g(x)= e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x|<1}, f(x,y) = \frac{g(y)}{x^2+(y-1)^2}$

Comment: I can imagine why this is a counterexample. The infimum of the radius of convergence of $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ over $y$ is zero. But I am unable to give a rigorous proof.